# Data binding in android studio project

Tags: android, sqlite, android-recyclerview

https://github.com/abbisQQ/taskmaker/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/google/developer/taskmaker/data/TaskAdapter.java

In line 87 i need to bind the data to the views any idea on how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

all you need to do is take holder object and name view and set text

```
 holder.nameView.setText("some_text");
 holder.imageView.setImgaeResource(R.drawable.image_view);
```